# Kubernetes: Cannot connect to service when using named targetPort

Tags: kubernetes

Here's my config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-deployment
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: 338f54d2-8f89-4602-a848-efcbcb63233f
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: 338f54d2-8f89-4602-a848-efcbcb63233f
        svc: app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: server
          ports:
            - name: http-port
              containerPort: 3000
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 128Mi
            requests:
              memory: 36Mi
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: db-env
            - secretRef:
                name: oauth-env
          startupProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: http
              path: /
            initialDelaySeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 1
            failureThreshold: 10
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              port: http
              path: /
            periodSeconds: 15
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-service
spec:
  selector:
    pod: 338f54d2-8f89-4602-a848-efcbcb63233f
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: http-port
```

When I try that I can't connect to my site. When I change `targetPort: http-port` back to `targetPort: 3000` it works fine. I thought the point of naming my port was so that I could use it in the `targetPort`. Does it not work with deployments?

Comment: Are you curling the service ip directly? or ingress?

Comment: I've just test it with `targetPort: http-port` in a `k3s` cluster and it works fine for me... Please consider that  wih `ClusterIP` type (Which is your Service type), you should be in the cluster and then curl your service, otherwide it is not gonna works and it is nothing to do with `targetPort: http-port`

Comment: @HKBN-ITDS Ingress. Trying to connect through my domain, in a browser. Here's the full example (output from `kustomize build`) https://pastebin.com/m8shig66 (but without the port names. This works)

Comment: @Ali Does it not work when behind Ingress? I want to expose this service publicly.

Comment: @ mpen Is your issue resolved?

Comment: @FariyaRahmat No, I still don't know how to use named ports when also using Ingress (and also not sure why that's relevant)

Comment: Please refer to the github [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-multicluster-ingress/issues/196) which may help you to resolve your query.